# Slim 404 when moved to godaddy from local turnkey vm

Tags: php, slim

So, I had a working application on a turnkey VM using slim and I decided to move it all to a hosted server when I started having issues with Slim. I got 404 on my endpoint calls. I then brought up fiddler and did a call directly to the index.php that contains the Slim endpoints. I got 404 on that. I then removed all the Slim code from index.php and called it again. This time I got 200. Adding back in the slim code a line at a time it didn't bring back 404 until I brought back

```
$app->run();
```

The test calls from fiddler where all directly to index.php and not to an endpoint within it.
Does anyone know what I need to do here? I have no rewrite rules set up in my htaccess.

Comment: You must setup the rewrite rules in .htaccess

Comment: @MikaTuupola when I was using it on the turnkey vm I didn't need to set up any rewrite rules. However it is now on a windows server rather than a linux one if that makes any difference.

Comment: @MikaTuupola I set it up using the .htaccess that slim provides. When that didn't work I was told that it needed to be a web.config because it's a windows server. I tried it with a web.config file from the example in the slim docs and it still doesn't work.